# Big-O algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm

The questions:
[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2706/image2ot.jpg](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2706/image2ot.jpg)

What I've done:
[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/9192/image3sc.jpg](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/9192/image3sc.jpg)

But I've got totally no idea the difference between 3.5 and 3.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're a bit more careful in your solution to 3.5, the difference will be a bit clearer. Your first line

```
T(n) <= n/4 (lg n)/4 + 3n/4 (3 lg n)/4 + n
```

isn't quite right. First of all, the inductive assumption is that there is a constant `C` such that

```
T(n) <= C n log n
```

so you probably should keep that `C` around. Second, you're skipping the step where you remove the floor function. What you *really* know is (ignoring the constant `C` for simplicity) is

```
T(n) <= floor(n/4) lg (floor(n/4)) + floor(3n/4) lg (floor(3n/4)) + n
```

So how do you take care of the floor? Well, `floor(x) <= x`; but what about `lg(floor(x))` (which shows up twice)? The key here is that `lg` is an increasing function, so `lg(floor(x)) <= lg(x)` also. So

```
T(n) <= n/4 lg(n/4) + 3n/4 lg(3n/4) + n
```

Now clean it up with some properties of logarithms (you *will* need to use that hint about `lg 3`) and finish your inductive step.

OK, so knowing that, what's the difference with 3.6? Well, now you have the ceiling function instead of the floor function, so you can't just ignore it. But

```
ceiling(x) <= x + 1
```

so you can work similarly, with some extra `+ 1` factors lying around. Try to use their hints, and it should be fine.

Comment: Good answer. This is as much support as we can give.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to show the key points but leave the details for the poster. If you feel like I should give more or less detail, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

The difference bettween 3.5 and 3.6 is the ceil and floor functions in T(n/4). Other than that they are identical. And as far as i can tell the difference does not matter to the calculations for O(T(n)) as you can see from the expected results.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think it helps. Notice that the text in 3.6 claims that the exercise is difficult, so something must matter here.

Comment: The difference will, presumably, be in showing how fast the series converges. But aside from that the attack should be the same.

Comment: @dmckee: O(n log n) is not about convergence whatsoever. For example, sin(x) is in O(1), yet sin will never converge.

Comment: Sorry wrong word. I should have said terminates. The recurence relation generates a series. A terminating series. How fast the series terminates depends on the choice of floor or ceiling, and you have to show how the termnation is bounded to finish the problem.